# WIndows 7 "snap" and "live previews" effects for Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux

I really like the Windows 7 "snap" effect. That is, when you drag a window to either side of the screen, it resizes the window to be half the desktop size.

I also like the "live preview" that creates a thumbnail when you mouse over something on the task bar.

However, I'm running Ubuntu (Linux) 9.10, I am curious to know if there is a solution (not using virtual machines) that will mimic these effects on Linux, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.detector-pro.com/2008/12/set-up-compiz-settings-manager-and-make.html) describes how to set up compiz with windows previews, but [they don't work when the window is minimized](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/4390/).

1. Enable compiz:

   - Go to System -> Preferences -> Appearance
   - Click on the Visual Effects tab
   - Click the "Normal" radio button (I think it's called normal -- whatever the setting between None and Lots is).
2. Install compizconfig-settings manager:

   - `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
3. Enable Window Previews:

   - System -> Preferences -> Compizconfig Settings Manager
   - Find Extras section
   - Check Window Previews
   - If it says you need to enable other plugins to make it work, say yes.

I don't know how to do the snap effect..

EDIT: [This](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/aero-snap-ubuntu-linux.html) describes a way to make Compiz do something Aero-snap-like. According to [this](http://lifehacker.com/5402090/emulate-windows-7s-aero-snap-sizing-in-linux):

> Two caveats apply to this trick, though. One is that you seem to lose the ability to drag windows horizontally into your next workspace. The other is that, depending on how you set it up, a dual monitor setup might not give properly sized windows.

---

Another update: GNOME 3 supports window snapping out-of-the-box. It doesn’t have a taskbar though, so there's no possibility for window previews.

Answer (score 1):

KDE 4.4 has the snap features enabled by default.
I'm not a fan of it, but it's there.

KDE4 has a Kwin plugin for the "Live preview" built in as well.  I don't remember the name, but it was something like Taskbar Thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the snap functionality by following the instructions here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/aero-snap-ubuntu-linux.html